# Bulk Update in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site which has client side and admin side. There is a table called account History.
which contains fields like uid | accountBalance | PaymentStatus | Date.

Now this table has to be updated every month for all the paid users and the table is bulk. So what is the best way to update the table every month.Do i need to select all the uid's and update.

Comment: Update the table every month manually or automatically? elaborate a bit more please :-) thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE History
SET accountBalance=val1, PaymentStatus=val2, Date=val3,
WHERE PaymentStatus=true
```

I do not know what the values are, but it should look something like this :)

Comment: I want to update this table for all the users in the table. each users balance will be calculated on the fly and update it

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like following query.

```
update history SET PaymentStatus="Paid" where accountBalance>00
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create an windows service to call either an executable or to post data to a web page;
add a timer inside your windows service and it acts exactly like a cron job.

Comment: no need to create a service when you can make simple scheduled task to run a php script in the same manner as a cronjob. You only need a service if it needs timings of less than 1 second I believe